# Compare fields over union

Tags: mysql

I would like to UNION two tables and compare a field across them.
The system I run the queries in do not allow multi queries and setting up variables. 
The code below generates an error on the WHERE clause.
Is there an alternative way for doing that on MySQL 5.7?

```
SELECT * FROM (

    SELECT 
        t1.field1, 
        t1.field2 
    FROM table_1 t1

    UNION

    SELECT 
        t2.field1, 
        t2.field2
    FROM table2 t2
    WHERE t2.field2 = t1.field2

) AS bar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query gives you the same result.

```
SELECT * FROM (

    SELECT 
        t1.field1, 
        t1.field2 
    FROM table_1 t1

    UNION

    SELECT 
        t2.field1, 
        t2.field2
    FROM table2 t2
    WHERE t2.field2 in (SELECT field2  FROM table_1)

) AS bar
```

If you have a WHERE Clause on t1 you have to add also in the subquery